# Https get call results in 400 Bad Request in android

Tags: android, ssl, httpsurlconnection

So i have a webpage which i trying to access via a HttpsURLConnection. The certificate issued is by Digicert CA-3.However I always get a response as 400.The android developer website, [wikipedia example](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#HttpsExample) works fine.This website also opens on chrome on the device.I want to know if this could a be a problem with how I am invoking the call.or what could be the issue

```
    URL url = new URL(strUrl);
    HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url
            .openConnection();
    SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getDefault();
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(false);
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslcontext.getSocketFactory());
    int code = urlConnection.getResponseCode(); //always 400 :(
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should double check the URL you are using.. It is mostly because of client's Bad Request..

Comment: used the same url from chrome on the device.that works.It even works in a webview

Comment: Try debugging your URL from your device in the [APP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sourcestream.android.restclient&hl=en)

Comment: @Femil..If it works from a  webview.why will it not work via a rest client?